# Ubuntu external dual monitors set up problem

Tags: ubuntu, multi-monitor, x-server, display-settings

I am new to *nix world. I have a Lenovo T440 laptop with Ubuntu 13.10 and looking to dock in its station. I have 2 ASUS external monitors connected to it. Ideally, I am looking to have the display in the external monitors, with extended view and no display in the laptop when I dock it. But I get a twin view in the external monitors, which are extended views of my laptop. When I check the display settings, it does recognize just one external monitor, instead of 2. It has an intel graphics card and does not have a nvidia one. How do I fix this?